# ajax amateur: how to send POST and get the array into the server?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

As the title says I've started to use ajax and jQuery and I have this problem. I send an array containing two arrays with json to the page 'ingrcomp2.php'. This is the code:

jQuery:

```
var productos=new Array();
var cantidades=new Array();
var combinado= new Array(2);

combinado[0]=productos;
combinado[1]=cantidades;        

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(combinado);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ingrcomp2.php",
    data: $('form').serialize(), 
    cache: false,
    success: function(){
        alert("OK");
    },  
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
    }   
});
```

HTML (`llenar_especial` is a function to display a select):

```
<table class="t-datos">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="sel_usuario">Usuario que la solicita:</label> 
            <?php include("funciones/select.php"); llenar("usuario",0,1);?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="sel_productos">Producto:</label>
            <?php llenar_especial("productos");?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="cantidad">Cantidad</label>
            <input type="text" name="cantidad" id="cantidad">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

PHP (ingrcomp2.php):

```
$array = json_decode($_POST['data']);
$fecha_compra=date("Y-m-d");
$hora=new DateTime();
$hora->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Bogota'));
$hora=$hora->format('H:i:s');

$usuario=$_REQUEST['sel_usuario'];

$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sima") or
die("Problemas en la conexion a la Base de Datos SIMA");

for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){    
    $compra=$array[1][i];
    $producto=$array[0][i];
```

How could I get to the array? And how could I get the select values?

Comment: without digging into your code too deeply, I'd suggest `var_dump($_REQUEST)` to get a detailed look at what your ajax call is sending.

Comment: array (size=3)
  'sel_usuario' => string '1045895621' (length=10)
  'sel_productos' => string '1' (length=1)
  'cantidad' => string '' (length=0)
and no, it doesn't send the multidimensional array...

Comment: At a glance it doesn't look like you're sending anything back for the JavaScript to get. You've set your arrays in PHP, but that's the end of the snippet. Try doing something like JSON_encoding the array you want to send back to the JavaScript and doing and ending with an echo $myJson (or whatever you named the encoded array)

Comment: it doesn't send the multi dimensional array from jquery to the php server how can i get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $('form').serialize() creates a query string of the form data, not JSON. You create the jsonString, but you are not passing that in your request.

Comment: i already fixed it! i used serialize() for the fields in the form and used JSON for the array and sent it through a hidden input. but now i have something else to fix